# Adding an item to a copy of a list unexpected behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, logic

I present  you two `functions`:

```
class Message:
def __init__(self, text, log):
    self.text = text
    self.log = log

def copy(self):
    return Message(self.text, self.log)

def add(self, more):
    self.text += more
    self.log += more
    return self
msg1 = Message("",[]).add("A")
msg2 = msg1.copy().add("B")
print(msg1.text, msg1.log)
print(msg2.text, msg2.log)
```

This `prints`

> A ['A', 'B']
>   AB ['A', 'B']

Here is where the unexpected thing (to me) happens -

```
list_1 = [1]
list_2 = list_1.copy()

list_2 += 'b'
print(list_1)  # prints [1]
print(list_2)  # prints [1,'b']
```

So, I can't seem to understand why the behavior isn't the same as I use += in both functions. I've read the docs for `object.__iadd__` but couldn't really understand the solution to my problem from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you are passing the same object (`[]`) to both `msg1` & `msg2`. When you modify that object with `msg1`, `msg2` also sees that change.

If you want to use a different object in `msg2`, you need to copy over `log` as well:

```
def copy():
    return Message(self.text, self.log.copy())
```

And this is what you're doing in the second case, which is why it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Doesn't the msg1.copy() create a completely new list? for example, `list[:]` allows me to adjust whatever i copied as long as its a simple list

Comment: `msg1.copy()` is _your_ code. Which doesn't do any copying. Just assignment. If you want python to create new objects you have to tell it to do so.

Comment: Sorry for possibly asking the same thing but I don't really understand. It's not that I want anything to happen, I'm just testing the behavior of lists. By using `msg1.copy()` do I not create a list in a way that could have been `something = self.log[:]` ?

Comment: You do realize that `msg.copy()` is the method _you_ have defined in the `Message` class. Just by calling a method `copy()` doesn't make it copy anything. In your case, the `copy()` method you have defined does not do any copying.